# Sitecore PAAS Publishing Target

Tags: paas

We are working on Sitecore 9.0 Update 2 in PAAS and need to set up the extra publishing target for production environment . Has some body done this before in PAAS.

Comment: There was a slight change on how to add publishing targets in Sitecore 9. Check out my blog post https://tothecore.sk/2018/05/10/adding-publishing-targets-in-sitecore-9/ . I assume same steps should be applied also for PaaS. Please try and if it's working, I will create answer for this.

Comment: And welcome to great Sitecore community Alivor :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract `Sitecore.Web.dacpac` and `CreateUser.Web.sql` files from `Sitecore 9.0.2 rev. 180604 (Cloud)_cd.scwdp.zip`
2. Deploy the dacpac to your SQL Azure server [using SSMS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/deploy-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-2017#deploy-a-dac-using-the-wizard)
3. Open the `CreateUser.Web.sql` , change the password to something unique and secure, and then run the script on your newly deployed database
4. [Follow the rest of the standard setup](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/10322/1278)

Comment: Since we have separate CM & CD Roles Objective of extra publishing instance is that it should behave as  Preview Instance for Content Authors . How will the extra website will be created on CM which will act as Staging instance

Comment: Make another site in site config with that database.